# Confusion about return function and Monad

Tags: haskell

Sorry, I am a newbie to Haskell. This questions may be very easy...

From Hoogle, `return` signature is `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`
and `head` signature is `head :: [a] -> a`

Before I did this `head $ return [1,2,3]`, I thought that ghci would throw errors because `m [a]` is not the same `[a]`. But to my surprise, it returned `[1,2,3]`. And `tail $ return [1,2,3]` returned `[]`. Why?

One more question:

I wrote a function to generate random number:

```
drawFloat :: Float -> Float -> IO Float
drawFloat x y = getStdRandom (randomR (x,y))
randList = mapM (const $ drawFloat 2 10) [1..10] -- generate a list of random numbers
```

When I want to get the head of the list, I first tried `head randList` (failed) but `head <$> randList` worked. What is `<$>`? Can someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I thought that ghci would throw errors because `m [a]` is not the same as `[a]`.

Maybe not, but `m [a]` and `[b]` can unify! For example, we can set `m ~ []` and `b ~ [a]` so that `m [a] ~ [] [a] ~ [[a]]` and `[b] ~ [[a]]`. Then we just need to check that `[]` is a `Monad`, which it is. And this is just what's happening:

```
> return [1,2,3] :: [[Int]]
[[1,2,3]]
```

Then it should be clear why `head` returns `[1,2,3]` and `tail` returns `[]`.

> ```
> randList = mapM (const $ drawFloat 2 10) [1..n]
> ```

As a comment, not answering your question yet: this is better spelled `replicateM n (drawFloat 2 10)`.

> `head randList` (failed) but `head <$> randList` worked. What is `<$>`?

The problem here is that `head` is still expecting a list. Before, when you were using `return`, the monad hadn't been chosen yet, and so it could be chosen to be `[]`; but here, it's clear that the monad you're using is `IO`. So `head` can't make progress. The solution is to teach `head` how to handle `IO`. There are many ways, and `<$>` is one of them; it has this type:

```
> :t (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The way to read this is: given a pure function, teach it how to handle `IO` (or any other kind of effect that qualifies as a `Functor`). For example, it also has this type:

```
(<$>) :: ([a] -> a) -> IO [a] -> IO a
```

There are several other kinds of teachers. Two commonly used ones are `<*>` and `=<<`:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t (=<<)
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Read the first as: given an effectful computation that produces a pure function, produce a function that can handle effects. The second should be read as: given a function which has some effects before it produces its output, produce a function which can handle effects.

At this point, if these explanations aren't helpful, you should turn to one of the many [excellent monad tutorials](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_tutorials_timeline) available elsewhere on the web. My personal favorites are [You Could Have Invented Monads!](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) and [All About Monads](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_about_monads).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question:

`return` takes a "raw" value and gives you a monad with the value "wrapped" in it. Since you are using `head` and `tail` on `return [1,2,3]` , the monad in question is the list monad `[]`. So in this context,

```
return [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3]]
```

apply `head` and `tail` on it, you will get `[1,2,3]` and `[]`, respectively.

On the second question, note that the type of `randList` is `IO [Float]`. So it's not a list any more, but a list inside a monad. To apply any function to the content of the monad, you can use `fmap` (`<$>` is its infix shorthand), which has the type:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

[A monad is always a Functor](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal). So what `fmap` does, is that it takes an ordinary function, (`head` in your example), and a monadic value, applies the function to the "content" of the monad, and returns a return-value of the function wrapped in the same monad `f`.